# Sequelize Query not working for pagination

Tags: node.js, pagination, sequelize.js

I'm trying to paginate a query using node.js / sequelize. Here is the working code (non-paginated):

```
    async records (req, res) {
    try {
      const data = await db.query(
        `SELECT rec_id,  User_File.user_id AS client_id, doc_name, created_on
        FROM User_File
        JOIN client_statuses ON User_File.status_id = client_statuses.status_id
        ORDER BY created_on DESC`)

    res.status(200).json(data)
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(data)
    }
  }
```

I tried the following and it gives me a connection refused error:

```
async index (req, res) {
    try {
      const data = await UserFile.findAll({ 
        attributes: ['rec_id', ['User_File.user_id', 'client_id'], doc_name, created_on],
        offset: 5, 
        limit: 5,
        order: ['created_on', 'DESC']
       })

    res.status(200).json(data)
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(data)
    }
  },
```

I also need to do the join in paginated version but not sure how...

Comment: attributes must be single quotes 'doc_name' , 'created_on' .

Comment: Also it should be db.UserFile.findAll.

Comment: @Prabhjot Singh Kainth I added the '' and db, still the same error.